# Microsoft Graph binary photo to file in Django

Tags: python, django, base64, microsoft-graph-api

Ok, I am connecting my Django app to Microsoft Graph API to get my user photo. The problem is that I cant  find how to transform the 64base not encoded binary data to a file I can use. I have been reading and searching for about 2 hours, with no luck.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got confused among Microsoft API manual and base64 information everywhere. I just needed to write the raw binary from Microsoft Graph API to a jpg file openend in binary mode, and thats was it.